# How do I get the username in an OOB application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a current silverlight app that runs within an asp.net browser window, as part of our intranet site.

I really need to have the username from the system on who is logged in.

I have a test system running as a OOB, that will perform the required actions to get the username from the system.

The question i have is this....   can the OOB silverlight application still reside in the intranet page as it did when it was not flagged as an OOB application?

thanks
tony

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4 OOB you can use the AutomationFactory when the App is running with elevated permissions.

```
var username = "";
if (App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
    using (dynamic shellObj = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Network"))
        userName = shellObj.UserName;
```

Note that you need to reference

- Microsoft.CSharp.dll and
- System.Core.dll

Read more on this topic on [Justin Angels Blog](http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures#BlogPost=CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures)

If you are deploying a Silverlight 4-application it has to run out of the browser as the sandbox inside the browser does not allow ElevatedPermissions. If you decide to use Silverlight 5 you can enable ElevatedPermissions with an administrative account for in-browser apps (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx).

Though you can of course run the app inside the intranet-page it has no elevated permissions as long as you (or the user) don't install and run it OOB. Thus the app will not be able to access the username.
It seems this restriction is partially gone with Silverlight 5 but I have not tested this, yet and cannot tell you if you could go the way described above.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess how you're going to use the username, but if you're planning to use it for authentication or authorization, you should do a bit more research.

If you want to actually authenticate the user, the server must be the one to do so. eg: asking for a username & password, windows authentication, etc.  The username (and even the domain) that's running on a PC shouldn't be trusted to be correct.